# Subtracting large number of hours from a set number(1000-650)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to figure out how many hours an intern can still work in a year. The intern is allowed to work 1000 hours total. I have a running total of how many hours the intern has worked so far. But when I try to get a simple calculation going like `=1000-(calculated hours)` Currently his hours are 666:10 and the result of the formula is 23333:50. This is not making sense to me.

How do I get this to work?

I've tried `=TEXT(1000-J1,"[h]:mm")` *(J1 is the calculation)*

I've tried `=1000+J1` which gives me 24666:10.

What can I do to figure out how many hours are left from 1000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `TEXT` function to format the value with the `[h]:mm` format, it assumes the value is measured in days, not hours. So you need to divide by 24 to convert your number from hours to days. Try `=TEXT((1000-J1)/24,"[h]:mm")`.

Comment: That is closer, now I'm getting a result of 972:14

Comment: This gave me an idea though I changed your formula a little to this: `=TEXT((1000/24)-J1,"[h]:mm")` and now I get the correct value of 333:50

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. Feel free to accept this answer by clicking the green check mark so that it will no longer be considered an unsolved question.